# Как открыть в браузере локалхост 3000 проект который делаю в React?

Tags: reactjs, консоль

Как открыть в браузере локалхост 3000 проект который делаю в React?
Я начала проект вчера и открыла при помощи команды npm start.
Сегодня уже не открывается.

когда я задала npx create-react-app nameProject >
то выбрала имя проекта "flowerbook"
теперь путь к package.json'npm изменился из \React_LarisaGrigoras\package.json'npm
в: React_LarisaGrigoras\flowerbook\package.json'npm
Как поменять путь и запустить проект в браузере?

Как открыть заново?
Вот что пишет в консоли
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path F:\8-AcademyRapido\7_React\React_LarisaGrigoras\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\8-AcademyRapido\7_React\React_LarisaGrigoras\package.json'npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Answer (score 1):

убрала папку по середине и все разрешилось

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулась с такой ситуацией. Решение заключалась в вводе этих команд:

1. cd my-app
2. npm start

Оставлю ответ тут на всякий)